# How to test if a HashSet Contains something in a TextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, hashset

I have been trying to test if my text field contains whatever is in my hashset but for some reason it is not working here is my code :

```
int WrongCounter = 0;
int RightCounter =1;
boolean isOver = false;
while(!isOver){
    question.setText("You have a "+RandomWord.length()+" letter word " + set);
    char input = scan.next().charAt(0);
    hangMan(WrongCounter);
    if(set.contains(ansField.getText().charAt(0))){
        set.remove(ansField.getText().charAt(0));
        right.setText("You are right");
        RightCounter++;
    }
    else if(!(set.contains(ansField.getText().charAt(0)))){

        right.setText("You are wrong!");
        WrongCounter++;
    }
    if(set.size()==0||WrongCounter ==8){
        isOver = true;
        hangMan(WrongCounter);
    }
```

here is the hangMan method

```
private void hangMan(int wrongCounter) {


        switch(wrongCounter){
        case 1:
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |\n     |\n     |\n___|___");
            break;
        case 2 :
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |\n     |\n     |\n___|___");

            break;
        case 3:
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |            O\n     |\n     |\n___|___");
            break;
        case 4 : 
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |            O\n     |           /\n     |\n___|___");
            break;
        case 5:
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |            O\n     |           /|\n     |\n___|___");
            break;
        case 6 :
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |            O\n     |           /|\\\n     |\n___|___");
            break;
        case 7 :
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |            O\n     |           /|\\\n     |           /\n___|___");
            break;
        case 8 : 
            hangMan.setText("     -------|\n     |            O\n     |           /|\\\n     |           / \\n___|___");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Whenever I try this program it crashes and I have no Idea why

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: It doesent exactly crash it just freezes and I have to close it out

Comment: That would indicate that `isOver` is never being set to true. is `set.size()==0||WrongCounter ==8` ever true?

Comment: Well, you terminate the while loop before you do the Hangman thing, you set the boolean to false which ends the whole loop.

Comment: Yes I originally made this program for console but I was transferring it to jFrame and thats when the problems came up

Comment: it Crashes whenever I put something in the textfield and press enter

Comment: Post that stack trace.

Comment: @user3097544 It's going to be tough to help you if you don't provide  a stack trace, or post a working example (for example, we have no way of determining what hangMan(int) does). In addition, you shouldn't be using a Scanner in your GUI application.

Comment: No its initialized to false before that while loop begins

Comment: I mean to true. Sorry.

Comment: I set it to true when set.size()== 0 or wrongCounter == 8

Comment: As I said before it doesent print the stack trace it just freezes on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a crash, that's an infinite loop. The program becomes unresponsive because you are probably executing this code inside an `ActionListener` attached to the `JTextField` or a `JButton` which is called by the EDT thread.

A GUI java application is not like a console application, there are multiple threads involved and you should not block the event thread with a loop like in your example. You have some unused code:

```
char input = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

which was blocking in your console version for input. Now you don't need a loop anymore because it's the user itself which will repeat the action on the user interface and call the `actionPerformed` method multiple times.

What do you want to do exactly? Verifying that the entered text is a permutation of the hidden word? Or just check the first character? In both situations you should remove the loop and store your variables outside the `actionPerformed` method:

```
int wrongCounter = 0;
int rightCounter = 0;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  char currentCharacter = textField.getText().charAt(0);

  if (set.contains(currentCharacter)) {
    ++rightCounter;
    // whatever
  }
  else {
    ++wrongCounter;
  }

  if (set.size() == 0 || wrongCounter == 8)
    hangMan();  // doesn't need parameter anymore, it's outside the method
}
```

Comment: A console program can't work easily in a GUI context, they work in a different way

Comment: See also ["Concurrency in Swing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: @Jack Wait I have another question now this works but My randomWord variable now generates a new Word everytime I input a letter how would I fix that?

Comment: Because you have it inside actionPerformed, that is called every time the button is pressed. You should move it inside `JFrame` constructor or in a special `reset()` method.